# Material preview with three.js

Tags: dynamic, three.js, preview

I am working on a way to show materials in the browser. 
There will be one (or several) geometries and I want to choose some path and load 3 textures from a folder on my disk to the geometry.

So in every folder there will be one colormap, one specular map and one normal map.

On the left part of my browser should be the WebGL scene with the geometry. And on the right side should be some field where I can choose the path and load the texture folders.

I am new to `three.js` and my question is:

Is this possible using `three.js`? Is there a way to load textures in the browser? And can I put one specular, one normal and one colormap on my geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See the examples at http://threejs.org/ or in the examples folder in the download, many of them have textures, normal maps and specular maps.

Material preview can just be a scene of it's own like any other kind of "normal scene".

Comment: Hi yaku, thank you for your fast reply. I have downloaded an example with a blender export and replaced the existing geometry with the one I have exported out of blender. This works fine. But when I try to copy the texture parts of another example with spec, color and normal map and insert them in my file, it doesn`t work. Is there something special to consider, when I texture blender exports in three.js?

Comment: @user2524500 Maybe that is subject of a different question? What have you tried exactly and how it is not working? Are you getting errors, is the browser getting the correct path and actually downloading the files? There shouldn't be anything special with blender exports vs. other geometries, except maybe possible UV coordinate related problems. Anyway you could try first with simple geometry created in Three. Try to get color and spec working first, then tackle normal map as that may be harder to get working right (or use bumb map instead). Use only textures with power-of-two dimensions.

Comment: @user2524500 also in your use case it might be easier to just use `scene.overrideMaterial = mypreviewmaterial;` to force all geometries to use your preview material.

Comment: var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
 jsonLoader.load( "models/teapot.js", addModelToScene );
  
 var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
 scene.add(ambientLight);
 }
function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) 
{
 var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
 android = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 android.scale.set(10,10,10);
 scene.add( android );
}

Comment: this is the part where the material is defined in the example, but when I want to change something and add a map the geometry becomes invisible in the browser.

Comment: Yeah if there are problems loading the texture it will be invisible (or until the texture is loaded). use firebug or chrome dev tools to check for errors, wrong paths in textures (net tab). If you consider the original question answered, please mark it as accepted and post a new question if you keep having problems. Be sure to include the code that is causing problems (the map definition part).